# How can I make semantic-release abort and fail if it would release a new major version?

Tags: semantic-release

I would like to add a check to [semantic-release](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release) to only allow it to publish minor and patch releases. If it detects the need to perform a new major release, I want the process to be aborted and fail (instead of proceeding to perform the release). How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Existing Plugin

I have created an npm package for a plugin that does this.

[evelynhathaway/semantic-release-fail-on-major-bump](https://github.com/evelynhathaway/semantic-release-fail-on-major-bump)

```sh
npm install --save-dev semantic-release-fail-on-major-bump
```

**`.releaserc`**

```json
{
    "plugins": [
        "semantic-release-fail-on-major-bump",
    ]
}
```

### Custom Plugin

If the published package doesn't solve your specific needs, you can create a semantic-release plugin that implements the `verifyRelease` step and throws an error based on the next release type.

**`plugin/index.js`**

```js
function verifyRelease (pluginConfig, context) {
    if (context.nextRelease.type === "major") {
        throw new Error("We cannot publish breaking changes at this time.");
    }
}

module.exports = {verifyRelease};
```

[Learn how to make semantic-release plugins](https://semantic-release.gitbook.io/semantic-release/developer-guide/plugin)

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much!